# Set core speed - linux

Tags: linux, cpu-speed

```
Architecture:
**AMD** Opteron quad-core using 2 CPUs --- Numa system

Processor : x86_64 Operating System: GNU/Linux
```

I am trying to set the core freq to 2.2GHz(that being the max) on just one core of the die.  The other die completely turned off.

```
sudo sh -c "echo 0 > /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu1/online"
sudo sh -c "echo 0 > /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu3/online"
sudo sh -c "echo 0 > /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu5/online"
sudo sh -c "echo 0 > /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu7/online"
```

Therefore just the cores, `0,2,4,6 are turned on`

I have tried changing the `governor` to `performance` but it changes the frequency of other cores' when any other thread runs on it. 
For example:

```
if thread one runs on core 0: then its freq is 2.2GHz

when thread two starts to run on core 2: it gets it as 2.2GHz - Where as I am expecting it to work as 0.8GHz.
```

is there a particular way to just set the frequency of just one core permanently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try setting the governor to `userspace` (you may need to recompile your kernel if it isn't included) and then manually setting the frequency using `scaling_setspeed`.

Comment: Fortunately, the governor `userspace` is provided by my version of kernel and distribution. 

Can you expand on the later part?

Comment: Okay. quite simple. 

say
`echo userspace > /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpuX/cpufreq/scaling_governor`
where X is the core id

`cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_governor`

`cat /proc/cpuinfo | egrep 'processor|MHz'`

Comment: The `scaling_setspeed` file is in the same directory -- you should be able to echo the frequency you want into it (again it might be that this is not supported by your kernel).

Answer (score 3):

Following @Lars answer.

Here is the complete solution:

```
echo userspace > /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_governor

echo userspace > /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu2/cpufreq/scaling_governor

echo userspace > /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu4/cpufreq/scaling_governor

echo userspace > /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu6/cpufreq/scaling_governor
```

`yum install cpufrequtils` or `sudo aptitude install cpufrequtils`

Then,

```
sudo cpufreq-set -c 0 -f 2200Mhz

sudo cpufreq-set -c 2 -f 800Mhz

sudo cpufreq-set -c 4 -f 800Mhz

sudo cpufreq-set -c 6 -f 800Mhz
```

Let me know if i can be anymore help in this issue. thanks

Answer (score 0):

this command might work if the "cpufreq-set" one is missing:

```
cpupower -c 0 frequency-set -f 800
```

Comment: `linux-tools-common` package needed.